# Gcloud pubsub worker in JS

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm developing a worker in JS with setInterval to check every 10 second if there is some new message. I would like to know if the approach is correct with following code. Do you think I will have some performance problem? I'm running it as a single pod in kubernete.

```
const messageHandler = message => {
  sendRequest(message, (message, error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      message.ack();
    }
  });
};

subscription.on(`message`, messageHandler);

const timeout = 10;
setInterval(() => {
  subscription.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
  subscription.on(`message`, messageHandler);
}, timeout * 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing and registering your messageHandler listener every 10 seconds, the following are two better approaches:

1. Have a long-running message listener for incoming messages until ‘x’ amount of time  is hit since the creation of the listener.
2. Have a long-running message listener for incoming messages and only shut down the subscriber if ‘x’ amount of time has passed since the last message was received.

In the rare case that messages are delayed, it is possible the subscriber could shut down before receiving all the messages that were published. But if you set the timeout to a large number (on the order of minutes), this would be very unlikely.

See the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) for examples of creating a subscriber client. You can modify the timeout to a greater number. The client library uses [StreamingPull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull), which maintains an open bidirectional stream and receives messages as they become available  for maximum throughput and low latency.

Comment: The problem with both approaches is that I only get the incoming messages. I won't get the messages that I didn't send it with the "ack". That is the reason why I'm usings setInterval. When I start running again the subscriber I'll get all the messages.

Comment: Moreover I want to keep the subscriber all time running in case I get new messages.

Comment: For messages that you do not ack/nack, they will be redelivered to your subscriber after the [ack-deadline](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/subscriber.ts#L209) passes. You can configure the initial ack-deadline at the creation of your subscription (default is set to 10 seconds initially). So if you subscriber is still up and running, it will receive the redelivered messages (the ones you have not yet ack).

Comment: The client library automatically extends the leases of messages by increasing the ack-deadline used for redelivery. The max amount of time to allow for the deadline to be extended before redelivering is configurable via the [FlowControlOptions](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/subscriber.ts#L211) under [maxExtension](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L33).

Comment: Additionally, to prevent your subscriber from becoming overwhelmed, you can use flow control to limit the rate at which your subscriber receives messages.

Comment: With the implementation above, the subscriber still run but it doesn't get the messages that I do not ack. So I have to stop the worker and run it again to get those messages

Comment: Try checking your [FlowControl](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L23) setup, it might be limiting the number and the rate at which your subscriber receives messages.

Comment: Additionally, if you do not ack or nack the messages that you’ve received, they will count toward the total number of outstanding messages. Once the [maxMessages](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L35) limit is reached, the subscriber will not receive anymore messages until the outstanding messages are either acked or nacked (or expired and will eventually be redelievered after [maxExtension](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L33) period).

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but if you want your subscriber to be up and listening "forever", then I don't understand why you need to remove your listener at all.

So why not something like this:

```
const messageHandler = async message => {
    try {
        await doSomethingWith(message);
        message.ack();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error handling message: ${message.id}: ${err.message}`);
        message.nack();
    }
};


// Listen for new messages
subscription.on(`message`, messageHandler);
```